# How would you go about creating a globe?

Tags: mesh

I'm fairly new to blender and was wondering of the best way to create a 3D world map.

Ideally the countries, water, or anything I add would be 2 dimensional. ↓
[image]

I have tried to apply an image texture to a sphere as a reference, and use texture paint to create the map, but it always ends up very pixelated. (Besides the fact that altering the map would be difficult).

I have found some information guiding me into the path of creating a "spherical" cube or a sphere, and just creating, on top, shapes that could be modeled into countries. But despite that I still am not exactly sure where a good starting place would be.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Edited:

Here is the file that I was working on with the texture paint:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2gce3jHgyfiSgP7_aFwnytVsIX?e=6xrXl1
And the Image:
file:///C:/Users/carso/Downloads/Nasamap.zip
[image]

Sorry to switch on you, but I have decided against a 2D map. Rather this is what I am going for:
[image]

Right now I have an image texture applied, I was hoping to use a displace modifier with a black and white image, but it came out pretty rough. I was hoping there is a Manuel way of tracing every continent and country.
What I have currently:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2gce3jHgyfiSpG3ajCWo1suWiX?e=uyhgy2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should use a mercator map that works fine, then use this image as a background in an image editor (like Photoshop, Krita, Gimp...), create your own illustraition on a layer, and at the end import the finished illustration in Blender in order to replace the original map. Or at least draw the basic shapes in the image editor, import, and paint on the image in the 3D view in *Texture Paint* mode.

[image]

You could even directly paint over the reference map with a mix of 2 *Image Texture* nodes. Use a *Color > MixRGB* node to mix the mercator map and a white image, keep the second *Image Texture* node selected before painting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried your second suggestion with the use of nodes, but the paint still comes out pixelated. I will try an image editor though.

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file? If the image is large enough it should not happen @Carson Yoder